# Jquery and Sharepoint 2007 - Not playing nice

Tags: jquery

So I was asked to develop a directory system that would allow my team to search for various key contacts we interact with on a daily basis. I decided to make a custom list and customised the layout to the way i want it and that went all fine and dandy but where I ran into problems is with Jquery.

What I am trying t accomplish is implementing this Jquery plugin http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget. I had no luck with it at all, haven't been able to make it work at all. I currently have a look up select and ive been trying to to change the 2 select columns and get something a bit cleaner using this plugin. So i tried the following to get this to work with no luck.

1) Tried to figure out the best way to load the Jquery library. I put all my script into my Document library and referenced the scripts into the header of my site. Nothing is changed.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SERVIPCManagement/imc/mtlcoe/coe1/Shared Documents/Tools/Custom Scripts/Custom/Multiselect/jquery.multiselect.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Custom/Multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SERVIPCManagement/imc/mtlcoe/coe1/Shared Documents/Tools/Custom Scripts/Custom/Multiselect/test.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect();
});
</script>

</asp:Content>
```

2) Tried to load the scripts via the content editor web part by linking it to a file that has the following and nothing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SERVIPCManagement/imc/mtlcoe/coe1/Shared Documents/Tools/Custom Scripts/Custom/Multiselect/jquery.multiselect.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Custom/Multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SERVIPCManagement/imc/mtlcoe/coe1/Shared Documents/Tools/Custom Scripts/Custom/Multiselect/test.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect();
});
</script>
```

3) Tried to adjust the configuration of the multiselect like so, nothing happens as well.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $("select[title='title']").multiselect();
    });
    </script>
```

If anyone has any other dieads please let me know im about to give up this whole Jquery idea.

Comment: Script tags are not self closing. `<script />` is invalid. Either omit the slash and leave it as `<script>` or add an appropriate closing tag `</script>`...

Comment: Dude this was so stupid, I added the </script> and worked just fine. Spent litterly all night on this lol some reason I read on another forum that <script /> works best in Sharepoint due to timing issues.Can figure out how to close this topics but its now resolved thanks.

Comment: No problem. I added it to the answer below. If it works for you, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Script tags are not self closing. `<script />` is invalid. Either omit the slash and leave it as `<script>` or add an appropriate closing tag `</script>`.